# Jenkins fails to run chrome but work fine in Headless[Reference Checked]

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

If I am running my testng xml locally it works fine in both headless or without however, when I am running it with jenkins it is giving me error in case of not headless

```
if (Utility.fetchConfigPropertyValue("browserName", config_Property_File_Path).toString()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "../ams-common/Drivers/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setHeadless(true);
        options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
        options.addArguments("disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.addArguments("no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
    }
```

Error on Jenkins

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Kindly note I have checked related question but did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Please describe precisely how the linked duplicates don't address your question.